# Vector gives garbage values

Tags: c++, vector

I can't understand why I am getting garbage values ... I don't know how to get this to give me the values I set without separating the setdetails function.

I am not quite sure if the issue is with the loop or with the set method, I tried playing with almost every part of the code, but still I get the same exact garbage values ... I guess I am missing some thing out

```
 class Book
{

    int isbn;
    int price;

public: 

Book();
Book(int isbn,int price){

    isbn =0;
    price = 0;
}

void setDetails(int isbn,int price){
    this->isbn = isbn;
    this->price = price;
}


int getDetails()const{
    return isbn;
    return price;
}};

void fillvector(vector<Book>& mybook){

cout <<"how many books do you want to add ?"<<endl;
int loop;
int Isbn;
int Price;
cin>> loop;

for (int i=0; i < loop; i++){

    cout<<"ISBN : ";
    cin>> Isbn;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"price : ";
    cin >>Price;

    Book newbook(Isbn,Price);
    mybook.push_back(newbook);
}

}
void printvector(vector<Book>& mybook)    {

int size = mybook.size();

for (int i = 1; i <size; i++){

    cout<< "ISBN : "<< mybook[i].getDetails()<<endl;


}

}

main(){
    vector<Book> mybook;

    fillvector(mybook);
    printvector(mybook);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Notice that your second `return` in `getDetails` is never reached.

Comment: i believe you have not allocated memory for the instances of Book... Try using `new` keyword...

Comment: @TheDillo, Memory is allocated appropriately on `Book newbook(Isbn,Price);`

Comment: Code looks like a specially designed task with intentionally added errors and mistakes

Comment: True one cannot simply just use 2 returns back to back in one function <insert boromir meme>

Answer (score 3):

In your constructor, as you use the same name for your argument as your member, you have to add `this->`

```
Book(int isbn, int price) {
    this->isbn = isbn;
    this->price = price;
}
```

or

```
Book(int isbn, int price) :
    isbn(isbn),
    price(price)
{
}
```

Comment: Oddly enough, GCC does better on warnings than Clang here with `-Wall -Wextra`.

Answer (score 3):

You got some different mistakes. One of them cause code to output garbage. See corrected version with comments.

```
class Book
{

    int isbn;
    int price;

public: 

Book();
// Arguments are named same as members!
// This cause members to be uninitialized (i.e. contain garbage)
Book(int arg_isbn,int arg_price){

    isbn =arg_isbn;
    price = arg_price;
}

void setDetails(int arg_isbn,int arg_price){
    isbn = arg_isbn;
    price = arg_price;
}

// You cannot return two values this way! Only one at time.
// So, implement two methods returning each particular detail
int get_isbn()const{
    return isbn;
}
int get_price()const{
    return price;
}
};

void fillvector(vector<Book>& mybook){

cout <<"how many books do you want to add ?"<<endl;
int loop;
int Isbn;
int Price;
cin>> loop;

for (int i=0; i < loop; i++){

    cout<<"ISBN : ";
    cin>> Isbn;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"price : ";
    cin >>Price;

    Book newbook(Isbn,Price);
    mybook.push_back(newbook);
}

}
void printvector(vector<Book>& mybook)    {

int size = mybook.size();
// for loop was starting from 1, this seem not intended
for (int i = 0; i <size; i++){
    cout<< "ISBN : "<< mybook[i].get_isbn() << endl;
    // Output of price member could be added here
}

}

main(){
    vector<Book> mybook;

    fillvector(mybook);
    printvector(mybook);

return 0;
}
```

PS. Some style violations are left alone.